# MuleSoft: Sending Form Parameters in a PUT Request

Tags: java, rest, mule, esb

I'm trying to send a *PUT* request to my API with an object I stored in a variable

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="muletest" method="PUT" metadata:id="ca84aa12-874e-654a-3214-5a9f16e04d09" doc:name="HTTP PUT /muletest" source="#[flowVars.muleTestFromCSV]">
    <http:request-builder>
        <http:uri-param paramName="id" value="#[flowVars.existingAppointment.get(0).id"/>
    </http:request-builder>
</http:request>
```

and I get this Error:

```
ERROR 2016-02-24 17:48:44,016 [[omdcrv3].omdcrv3Flow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Response code 405 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
Type                  : org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@38e2c241
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/http/internal/request/ResponseValidatorException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Response code 405 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream (org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator:37 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/http/internal/request/ResponseValidatorException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 405 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:311)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:299)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:186)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:303)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:293)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:283)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:198)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.processParts(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:129)
    at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.process(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallba...
********************************************************************************
```

I use the same variable in a *POST* (#[flowVars.muleTestFromCSV]) and it works perfectly. I was assuming that *PUT* was like *POST* in terms of taking a Map as body but it doesn't give me the expected result.
(From documentation):

> Generate the Request Body with
>   Content-Type:application/x-form-urlencoded Whenever the message
>   payload is a Map, the connector automatically generates an HTTP
>   request with the header
>   Content-Type:`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The keys and values
>   of the map in the payload are converted into form parameter keys and
>   values in the body of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to get rid of:

```
<http:request-builder>
    <http:uri-param paramName="id" value="#[flowVars.existingAppointment.get(0).id"/>
</http:request-builder>
```

Set the Path same as like this:

```
<http:request config-ref="httpConfig" path="thePath/1" method="PUT" doc:name="Update"/>
```

Comment: perfect thanks. I thought that was what the *uri-param* was there for. Nevermind, works like that, ok for me.